# Observing and running a program when another program is ran

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Lets say I have One.exe and Two.exe. I would like to have a script that will run Two.exe as soon as One.exe is ran and finished loading.

Now, I was wondering what is the better way to do it:

- have a script that will be started along with Windows and just sit
  quietly in the background, listening for when One.exe will get
  started and loaded.
- Somehow attach a script to One.exe, so when it runs, the script runs
  Two.exe
- some other ideas that I don't have yet.

I haven't done any `batch` scripts yet, so I wanted get into the right way so I know what to search and read about.

Is my idea possible to get realized at all?

Comment: This is highly dependent on what "one.exe" is. You need a mechanism to determine when it is "finished loading" You tell us - how can you tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a simple delay after `one.exe` is launched with `ping` or `timeout` commands.